# Why output in this order?

Tags: java, overriding

```
abstract class A {

    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("methodA");
        methodB();
        showName();
    }

    public abstract void methodB();

    public void showName() {
        System.out.println("in showname base");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("methodB");
    }

    public void showName() {
        System.out.println("in showname child");
    }
}

public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.methodA();
    }
}
```

Output is :

> methodA
>   methodB
>   in showname child

**Question :-**

Since in overriding, the object type is considered. Is it the reason behind that class B's showName() method called not of class A's? If not then whats the cause of this output order?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Hey Paul, I am sorry but I dnt know how to format it.

Comment: Should we be answering questions on here that smell of a school assignment?

Comment: There is a code formatting button in the editor that looks like this: `{}` - go into the editor, select the code, then hit the formatting button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy:

```
    A a = new B();
    a.methodA();
```

here is known that a is object of `B` class, so every method that can be overriden in class `B` is used from class `B` if there is no overriding, then method from class `A` must be used.

Considering order:

you invoke `methodA` that is declared as:

```
public void methodA() {
    System.out.println("methodA");
    methodB();
    showName();
}
```

from inside of `methodA()` you invoke both `methodB()` and `showName()`. They are overriden in class `B`, and object a is `instanceof B`, so that's why they (from B class) are used.

**EDIT** as mentioned in comment:

@Jaikrat Singh, class B is still class A (child of it, but inheritance is relation of type: IS-A ). Class `B` has inherited methods from `A` class. So it has `methodA` as well. So it's better to say, that `methodA` is also called from class `B` but with is default code - the same as provided in class `A`

Comment: But I am not calling that overridden method from any objecttype. That method is being called from the body of another method which is being called because of reference type.

Comment: @Jaikrat Singh, class B is still class A (child of it, but inheritance is relation of type: IS-A ). Class `B` has inherited methods from `A` class. So it has `methodA` as well. So it's better to say, that `methodA` is also called from class `B` but with is default code - the same as provided in class `A`

Answer (score 4):

You created an object of type B, so all methods called on that object will be on class B. If class B does not implement some methods (like methodA), then Java tries to find a method in the parent class (A). You should read about polymorphism in object oriented languages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Comment: Best answer: explains polymorphism. +1

Answer (score 2):

While the object 'a' is declared as type A, it is instantiated as type B.  Polymorphism causes the methods of the instance type to be called rather than those of the declaration type, so because it is internally of type B, the showName() method of class B is called.

Comment: But I am not calling that overridden method from any objecttype. That method is being called from the body of another method which is being called because of reference type.

Comment: Even though methodA() is defined only in class A, it still runs through polymorphism to decide every method call within methodA(), so because showName() is defined in class B, it calls that showName() rather than the one defined in class A.

Comment: Hey thanks @Vulcan. I tried to select your answer too as "accepted answer" but I think only one can be selected at a time. Thanks for clarifying my thoughts. I was confused. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `a.methodA()`, since your object type is `B`, it will look for `methodA` first in `B`. Since there is no such method in `B`, it will look for this method in its super class, which is `A`. Finding `methodA` in class `A`, it will start to execute.

Executing, it will print `methodA` and start looking for the next called method (`methodB`), which is implemented in the `B` class, then it will print `methodB`.

The next called method is `showName`, which is implemented in both classes. Since Java will start looking for the implementation in the same class as the object type, it will find in its first attempt, which is class `B`.

The main rule is simple: Java will first try to find the method in the **object** type class (the name that goes after the `new` operator). If the method is not implemented there, it will start to go up through the super classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have the abstract class `A`, and it is extended by `B`.  Extends is equivalent to `B "is a" A`.  For example if apple extended fruit, `apple 'is a' fruit`.  It acts like a fruit but also does apple things that a banana wouldn't do.  So `B` acts the same way as `A`, but then also can do other stuff.  So in your example, your `B` overwrites two methods.  They will be called by every `B` object by default.  In order to access `A`'s methods from a `B`, you need to use the keyword `super` .

It is part of polymorphism (a key point in java programming) that an object will find any methods in itself first (even if they are overwritten from a parent) and then it will climb the tree of inheritance to find a method that isn't directly in that class.

For your example:

```
public void methodA() {
    System.out.println("methodA"); //This prints no problem.
    methodB(); //This searches the "B" class for a method called "methodB"  If it can't find it, it checks its parent for a "methodB"
    showName();//This searches the "B" class for a method called "showName"  If it can't find it, it checks its parent for a "showName"
}
```

The above code gets called.  You know this much (from other comments you made, I'm assuming this.)  Once the line `methodB()` gets called, your object of type `B` checks the entire B file for the method.  It would only jump up to `A` for the method if it didn't exist.  Then it would do the same for `showName()`.